# Javascript throw vs. return error object vs. callback

Tags: javascript, assembly, error-handling

I'm writing an assembler and simulator for a toy assembly language that I have my CS students use in class. I'm writing it in javascript with the idea that I could then build a simple UI in the browser which would show students how each instruction changes the state of the machine and such.

One question that I'm grappling with is the best way to return error information from the assembler when invalid assembly code is passed. The assembler has an extremely simple API at the moment:

```
var assembler = ... // Get the assembler object
var valid_source = "0 mov r1 r2\n1 halt";
var valid_binary = assembler.assemble(valid_source);  // String containing 0's and 1's

var invalid_source = "foo bar baz!";
var invalid_binary = assembler.assemble(invalid_source); // What should happen here?
```

I have a few thoughts about how this might work:

1. Construct and throw a new javascript Error object. This seems like overkill (and ultimately maybe not even helpful since the user wouldn't care about the javascript stacktrace, etc).
2. Return a string or object containing error information. Then the user of the assembler gets to make the choice about what to do with errors (if anything).
3. Change the assembler API to use a callback instead:

   `assembler.assemble(source, function(binary, error) {
     if (error) {
       // Handle the error
     }
     // Otherwise, do stuff with the binary
   });`
4. Something else entirely?

Any ideas, thoughts, or feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would change the assembler API, but not by adding a new parameter to the main callback. Add the ability to chain on some kind of `.catch(callback)` (where the `callback` will be called if something goes wrong in the `.assemble()` call). Then again, I'm not sure what `.assemble()` actually does, but introducing callbacks without asynchronous things seems unnecessary

Comment: Oh, interesting idea. I hadn't thought of that. Yeah, at the moment .assemble() just parses the input string synchronously so maybe a callback is unnecessary. I just like the way the callback syntax shows that there _could_ be an error instead of the function simply returning different types upon success or failure.

Comment: Looking over your #3 again, I guess another idea would still be to not add an extra error parameter, but provide another callback to `assemble` specifically for errors. So it would be like `assembler.assemble(source, successCallback, errorCallback)` (where `successCallback` would be called with the binary, or `errorCallback` would be called with an error message or something). Then you have a defined distinction between success and failure and the callback code doesn't have to do logic to check. I like this one better

Comment: Ah true. That could work as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your three options would work fine. Now from my perspective:

I would keep away from the third option because it gives the feeling it is an async function when it is not.

I would go for option 1 or 2. The first one is a little overkill but I think it is the most realistic approach to what compilers do. Exit with no zero code. But then you would need to add a try/catch block to handle the error.

So the next option is to return an error object. Seems the best option for me.

I recommend you to return an Error object. It is as simple as:

```
return new Error('Parsing error');

// Or with an error name
var error = new Error('Parsing error');
error.name = 'PARSING_ERROR';
return error;
```

One advantage to use the error object is that it gives you the stack trace and other handy stuff. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

Also, to check if there was any error just need to check the variable type:

```
if (typeof valid_binary === 'string') { /* no error */ }

// Or

if (typeof valid_binary === 'object') { /* error */ }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm actually feeling less and less inclined to construct javascript error objects (regardless of throwing or not), since I tend to think that this implies a programmer error in javascript, but really it represents programmer error in the assembly language. Perhaps returning a string or custom object with error information is the best way to go.

Comment: A custom error object will work. However I give you my opinion from a Node.js background where Errors that are not Error objects are frowned upon. Check Node.js modules, they are all full of Error objects. One of the main reasons is because it gives you stack traces!

Comment: Yeah, I've written node apps as well and I understand the usefulness of Error. But my point is that inheriting from Error doesn't actually make sense in this case since a javascript stack trace will be useless to anyone using the assembler. I.e., the javascript implementation of the assembler is not useful to debugging the assembly code.